# How can I group multiple controls together so that they are accessible by a method?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, containers, grouping

I have multiple groups of controls on my form that changes together on a specific event ... but the changes are everytime the same and only the names of the controls are different.

So I have to do:

```
label1.Text = "ready";
label2.Text = "let's go";
label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen
textbox1.Enabled = true;
textbox2.Enabled = true;
button1.Enabled = true;
button2.Enabled = true;
```

or

```
label1.Text = "not ready";
label2.Text = "just waiting to get ready";
label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
textbox1.Enabled = false;
textbox2.Enabled = false;
button1.Enabled = false;
button2.Enabled = false;
```

in each of the events, but for label3+label4 or label5+label6 etc. instead.

So my thought was, if it's possible to put the groups of controls in something like a container and then call a method with the container as parameter.

like:

```
setReady(container);
setNotReady(container);
```

and this method would then do all the stuff I want.

So my question is, how would such a method look like resp. how can I access controls inside a container in this way? Or is there maybe a better way to handle something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group them in a `List< Control >`

Answer (score -1):

You can try using a User Control, and then access to the User Control controls

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how the OP would do this and how it would solve the problem? As written, your answer looks much more like a comment.